# material android Chip is crashing when inflated in xml layout

Tags: android, androidx, material-components-android

Even if I don't do anything in code... looks like somewhere in view class drawable is created somehow and this crashes Chip as this is not allowed... Any help welcome.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at renetik.android.viewbase.CSView.inflate(CSView.java:104)
        at renetik.android.viewbase.CSView.getView(CSView.java:119)
        at renetik.android.viewbase.CSViewController.getView(CSViewController.java:405)
        at renetik.android.viewbase.CSViewController.getView(CSViewController.java:408)
        at renetik.android.viewbase.CSView.findView(CSView.java:108)
        at renetik.android.extensions.view.CSViewKt.editText(CSView.kt:22)
        at com.tanya.renetik.redriver.view.route.EditHouseFieldsController.<init>(EditHouseFieldsController.kt:15)
        at com.tanya.renetik.redriver.view.route.started.StartedAddHouseController.<init>(StartedAddHouseController.kt:31)
        at com.tanya.renetik.redriver.view.route.started.StartedRouteMapController$onCreate$2.invoke(StartedRouteMapController.kt:37)
        at com.tanya.renetik.redriver.view.route.started.StartedRouteMapController$onCreate$2.invoke(StartedRouteMapController.kt:17)
        at renetik.android.extensions.view.ViewKt$onClick$$inlined$apply$lambda$1.onClick(View.kt:51)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Do not set the background; Chip manages its own background drawable.
        at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.setBackground(Chip.java:397)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5200)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:824)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:172)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:94)
        at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:69)
        at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:65)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.<init>(AppCompatCheckBox.java:64)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.java:169)
```

In layout just something like this...

```
  <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/EditHouse_Category_Vacant"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Category_Vacant" />
```

My theme file is simple:

```
    <style name="DriverTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/driver_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/driver_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/driver_secondary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
ext.material_version = '1.0.0'
ext.appcompat_version = '1.0.0'
ext.play_version = '16.0.0'

Comment: What theme are you using for the activity that has this `Chip` in it? Does this theme define `android:background` ?

Comment: @BenP. I added my theme file, nothing special there...

Comment: Where is the Chip located? Is it in the action bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it, I was using this code to create top level layout:

```
view = FrameLayout(ContextThemeWrapper(this.context(), R.style.CSNavigationContainer))
```

And inside of this layout I have set white background what should be ok but...
Now I see what this ContextThemeWrapper actually do:

```
The specified theme will be applied on top of the base context's theme.
```

So by this my context theme was modified to contain background with white color and this somehow went to other views created later with this context and this crashed Chip as it don't allow background.

So I have to stop using ContextThemeWrapper , maybe I misunderstood real purpose, I wanted to apply style to my view programmatically, what actually worked, but it modified whole theme.

So I found library [paris](https://github.com/airbnb/paris) for aplying styles programatically and changed that code to:

```
  view = FrameLayout(context()).apply { style(R.style.CSNavigationContainer) }
```

now it works with the same style.

Answer (score 1):

Just my small workaround after one day of battling :/

```
class ChipCrashWorkaround(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int)
    : Chip(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    constructor (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?)
            : this(context, attrs, R.attr.chipStyle)

    constructor (context: Context) : this(context, null)

    override fun setBackground(background: Drawable) = try {
        super.setBackground(background)
    } catch (ex: UnsupportedOperationException) {
        warn(ex)
    }

    override fun setBackgroundDrawable(background: Drawable) = try {
        super.setBackgroundDrawable(background)
    } catch (ex: UnsupportedOperationException) {
        warn(ex)
    }
}
```

Well I can see clearly that somehow drawable is applied probably from theme to my chip even if I disable all customizations everywhere.. Wtf I don't know but have to move forward...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the library are you using? The exception is being thrown because chip manages its own background and doesn't support View#setBackground. Is it possible that a parent of your chip instance is trying to set the chip's background?

Comment: Hi, you mean like programmatically ? Or how exactly I can set background from parent ?

Comment: Well sure I know what is causing the crash... don't know how the color background gets applied though ... some background magic here...

Comment: Could you please verify whether the crash is reproducible in a very simple sample app, without using any of your custom views?

Comment: did you look at the solution I found ? There is explained very clearly how this happened https://stackoverflow.com/a/53287528/925135 , its not bug in material library for sure, but consequence of usage of ContextThemeWrapper. It's fore sure reproducible easily. But for sure Chip should not throw exception like this, it should warn and ignore background form theme or something... Thats my opinion.

Comment: Hi Renetik, thanks for the explanation and suggestion. I filed a ticket to make the change, you can track the progress at:
https://b.corp.google.com/issues/119564663